# Animate table cell with with text overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a table with x number of cells and I want them to fit into the table with width 100%, probably using

```
overflow: hidden;
```

on the anchor?

I do not care if the text gets cut of in its default state. The twist here is that on hover of the cell, I want to expand it to show all text, and in the meanwhile of course compress the other cells so it fits.

See the structure of today here http://jsfiddle.net/Bjolja/1haurmyw/

I want it to fit to the window. Any ideas?

**Update:**

I wrote cells, what it really is, is li-elements with display: table-cell to mimic the functionality of a table. I have media queries requiring li when using smaller devices. But the behaviour of the elements are like table cells.

Comment: Just to point out, these aren't `<td>`s they're `<li>`s

Comment: Thanks for poiting it out, I updated the question with a breif explanation.